# Magento 2 | removed bootstrap.css and it still loads it

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, css

I am not sure what has happened here...

That's the layout of my site now:

[image]

Looks like everything moved to the left hand side... Anyone came across the same issue?

I had a cached version of the site and only realised that now, not sure how long it was like this for.

---

**UPDATE**

I have found what the issue is but can't figure out how to delete it.

I installed a module yesterday and now I have a CSS conflict.

We have installed the extension, deleted static files, flush all the cache but it still loads the file from this location even tho the file no longer exist in that path!

[image]

Comment: Hymm what am I looking for?

Comment: I zoomed out to show the layout issue better. It does that on every zoom level...

Comment: did you merged your css files?

Comment: It's not merged. no :/